# Image in xAxis Echarts

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts, x-axis

#### Change the style of image rendered in xAxisLabel of ECharts

does anyone know how can i style images in xaxis label in ECharts.
I used this example to render image in xAxisLabel [richStyleExample](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-rich-text&edit=1&reset=1)
But somehow i cannot style the image (i only want to change the radius of it), however in the documentation I found this :

[image]

###### Does anyone knows how can I assign HTMLImageElement to this or somehow change the radius or style of the image?

I tried `borderRadius` in rich style, but it only works if the backgroundColor is not assign an image source.

Answer (score 1):

you have to give border width.

[EXAMPLE:](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-rich-text&edit=1&reset=1&code=MYewdgzgLgBA7gUwIZQBYIE4ElSRgXhgG8AoGGAZQFcwwBPALhgCUB5VgFQH0AFAQQ4AJGAGoYAcgD0AExRJJSCBARRJASwC2Ac0mIU6DJIg16XAIwAmABwA6AA5gt4gDRkYAYQA2IKtMYt2bn4hUQkZOQUlFXVtXWQ0TElgb186c2t7Rxc3ClQQRAwIJjZOXgFhMSlZKHlFZVVNHT0Ewwg8goh02wcnEgBfAG4SXGgYZQw1BAgAGSQAIwRPAmI3NvymKAwqBH6hkDsoNXBl0nJDqE8EJlPyGCgEAA8oJnEAdXiDShrD6DVgCHEbj6rjOIBAnkOdmubjOEy0WkwLyQDzUAJBt2RqJ4IDUYHuGGht1uUDodiuEjaSGk-UBRL6QPRlwRYGkhNu1SQTAA2uJ3GoSTA-J47KgkC4JHyBQAhFRi5wS_l0GAAcSQGg0YoAugy3FoJqyVkTLgAzZ4wMwABgtOtB4LmIAebPIazgGy2CHR5GN8SoGHJNyJECQADcEHwIFgNQjrvS6TaYA8-CiiobiaTyeJg0hPNtskSwGqMwARJB0NEwmCYmbzRZO27GkAYDVQfEvIhZnMIPq026xmDAtx0JOouskskvYAoBBaRt0PO3XGhwrkzbbT0wDnc8TUWhz-W8lJ-cXb9qYAGa9dV2YLTx1r2N5utmDGmjAQ7HAAUHe2AEpU0TyD9KBfTACQiHEUJvwQUJxAAH37AAdMB22zbZYIgsQoJg7shgA_t13IDUMC0XEmAsC0CJgCZgFQO9biguijVxBBBAQNQtFQM0AGYKIrPDs3YsAJwQPFMB7PCBzw8gd3oRjbnQdjOKYAAWXipNuOA1GkNAVLU9TK08QThNEjB53UuYkGAABrPUfBZdxwUbOSiU0JBo3gD5MBwcAIBsGS6D4gDJP0-0MGkTBmCpNQqCKS1KKJULwowV4tJ0sx4tuRLMAc7wCXEABiY1jSsKwzDMcSgoyrwfD8ZyYAUjizVUjLyAErQhIkYARPxMypIs6zbJoaQcqc_99Nc9zmgMbzIBsarUkCukWpgLKMEi6RotivTzMbJKUu02j0sWzLduyxy8sK4rSvK47grw3J8jPOqGqUmBmuO1rDPa4yeuW_qbIwOzhvOuryAm8kpq8kY_NPQoPvw-HVvWzaGDixHTuS1LDr-jGRouoqSrKiq4wkis-2C8ZJhTLkKwDW4Cw0DNJSVIURTlQKxwzCzTMozcYC5MwADYAFZ5TMAB2CiYB4i9As8GtbzGTAqevRZKKIqzsVxM06cDOgNHtTwKDUAAvckjvUiB9cN1givqbkpfEYWLQAUnEWX1Plm86obJsUCfcQiCQWCg76JC-iIOYQ7mPp-yIYAQ-APpuz-yyAaBvGXmIuYPwsZSLGcPOC6Ln9erw1bM4kfKkBrsuANW_adPNHGwoiqKYqYUX4bsKkNscbllLFi0Pf0wywBYtjGrIwXlskSQxlFak4ClHMCRgLv9JgOeF6pfJK4Kq0LTrolt8pJfbeNeoAA0mG2qTT8X_IL_qABNJgLf0uwQAgfkjg68Q4ScWPuyVENQwBdTInfPC1FaJjXUpyOB-k2r_y6iZYBeFQC5ReJdY06CAINjxMbM278rDLSJPcJ4uRd7L1XmRMhxJHhQCoUvfe-VD54PIYw5hT87YqBvjAKB-kKFMMfnAZ-Kg37N3hpwp4UpcYgyrlxJRHCGGyIxo3WBFhpEI03uQOYoNbiYNGgVJRXFiZSTuvpYABjyBGLXgVAm10VFnEYXI1uGBWHsPoS4tR7iNHv28c-cATDTbkgsFo3R_Z4Z9gkhlPmNNN5EDuOmF4GoHjigZhmNJG5SwpggpYvCSTOapNxBkwsJTQKyDLC8KJ6ltSkyWrTQKmSXjMxgDKGoddikSG5nXL2tYlYTCmKrTwvM5DcjMM7IeotzSWnqb2dcusYAtIVAKVU6p2Z4W6eIXplF-mK0psMhWYyajcnCVLKwBcYCCy4vM8gfZtSDCAA)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but it actually doesn't round the image but it does make the background of it rounded, i wonder if is there any possible way to assign HTMLImageElement to it , or at least control the overflow of the image after asigning border radius to it .